# In Excel VBA, how can I compare two ranges and copy an offset of one range into an offset of another if there's a match?

Tags: vba, excel

After some googling, I'm using the below:

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, ToCompare As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    Set CompareRange = Worksheets("names").Range("A1:A500")
    Set ToCompare = Worksheets("Main").Range("C1:C500")
    For Each x In ToCompare
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 2) = y.Offset(0, 1)
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Worksheet "main" column C contains a list of names that is a concatenation of the A and B columns (first and last names). Would this cause my program to not run?

Worksheet"names" column A contains names of people, and Worksheet"names" column B contains the data I want to copy to Worksheet"main" in column E if there's a match. Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nested loops to search for a match can be terribly inefficient. Instead, use the built-in `.Find` method. See the below code for an example, and let us know if you need added help working with it.

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim compareRange As Range
    Dim toCompare As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim cel As Range

    Set compareRange = Worksheets("Names").Range("A1:A500")
    Set toCompare = Worksheets("Main").Range("C1:C500")
    Set rFound = Nothing

    For Each cel In toCompare
        Set rFound = compareRange.Find(cel)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            cel.Offset(, 2).Value = rFound.Offset(, 1)
            Set rFound = Nothing
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```